# The unit sphere in a normed FDVS is compact

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

How do you prove that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional normed vector space then its unit sphere $ \{v : |v| = 1\}$ is compact? The textbook claims there is a one-line proof.

If $V$ is over $\mathbb{R}$ then this is a result of Heine-Borel. But how about in general? Also, how does one prove the converse for a general finite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Do you know that all norms on $V$ are equivalent?  Also, what do you mean by "the converse for a general finite-dimensional vector space"?

Comment: Yes. How would that help? And by converse I meant that if the unit sphere is compact then V is finite dimensional.

Comment: Hint: if $\dim V = n$ and $V$ is over a field $K$, then $V$ is isomorphic to $K^n$ and therefore isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Math1000 How is $K^n$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any field $K$? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @agrasin Sorry, I misspoke there. What I meant to say is that finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic up to dimension, cf. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Dimension_Characterizes_Isomorphism